# Automate a C script to work on multiple files

Tags: python, c

I am currently working with the downloadable script you can find on this site: 
http://mbio-serv2.mbioekol.lu.se/ARAGORN/

It is a '.c' script I turned into a '.o' using CodeBlocks. By default, the script analyzes a single input file providing another one as a result.

I would like to make this script work for a large amount of input files so I would need some automatization. For this reason, I would need to create another script able to open the directory where all my input files are located and then execute the '.o' on every single input file.

Thus I would be obtaining an output file for every of the input files.

I guess it must be something like:

```
open /.directory

i=0 

while 

(i < 'number of files to analyze') do {
    execute script.o (file i) > outputfilei.txt 
#save result for every input file
    i++
}
```

I am quite novel on programming so I have no clue how to deal with this. Any language should do, but I guess I would rather use Python since I a used to run its scripts on Terminal (I am using a Mac).

Thanks for your time and help forehand.

Comment: There is no such thing as a C script. If you want to create a Python script, you should add python tag instead of C. But without showing some prior effort, the question is rather off topic with any tag.

Comment: Nothing called C script.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified how you save the output from the multiple runs, but assuming you want it all on stdout (as the C program will print it by default), your best bet is actually a shell script (in Python, it will be more work to do the same thing):

```
#!/bin/bash
for file ; do ./aragorn (add your options here) $i ; done
```

Now, if you save it as `aragorn_many` (and make it executable), you could run it like this:

```
./aragorn_many file1 file2 file3 ...
```

(assuming both the compiled C and your shell script are in your current directory)